# Latest 5 images from each category displayed in a summary

Tags: php, mysql

*I have 2 tables in My database and I wanted a PHP output of the following, how can I do this?*

**Latest 5 Catname1 Images**
image42.jpg, image45.jpg ect ect

**Latest 5 Catname2 Images**
image41.jpg, image44.jpg ect ect

**Latest 5 Catname3 Images**
image43.jpg, image46.jpg ect ect

*I have 2 tables in mysqly layed out like this:*

**imagedb** (MySql Table name)
iid,iname,icat,idesc,itags,ithumb
41,Name41,2,desc41,tag41,image41.jpg
42,Name42,1,desc42,tag42,image42.jpg
43,Name43,3,desc43,tag43,image43.jpg
44,Name44,1,desc44,tag44,image44.jpg
45,Name45,2,desc45,tag45,image45.jpg
46,Name46,3,desc46,tag46,image46.jpg
Ect ect

**categories** (MySql Table name)
cid,cname,cdesc,ctags
1,catname1,catdesc1,cattags1
2,catname2,catdesc2,cattags2
3,catname3,catdesc3,cattags3

*Hope this makes sense. Thank you...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to create a loop in PHP that fetches the last 5 images from the `imagedb` table based on each category you want to use.

```
$categories = mysql_query("SELECT cid, cname FROM categories");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories)){
    echo "<strong>Latest 5 " . $row['cname'] . " Images</strong>";
    $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imagedb WHERE cid = " . $row['cid'] . " ORDER BY iid DESC LIMIT 5;");
    $images = array();
    while($image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query))
        $images[]  = $image['iname']; // change this to $image['ithumb'] etc for different fields

    echo '<p>' . implode(', ', $images) . '</p>';
}
```

That will print pretty closely what you have entered there, (assuming the ID of each image indicates when it was inserted (higher means newer).

There are probably cleaner ways of doing this, and depending on your implementation you might need to loop once to get the data then again to print it, however this should give you a good headstart.

Comment: Hi @phindmarsh. Very close. Each heading came out correctly.
Just the information between <p></p> didnt.

Comment: If you want different information for each image just change the part in the second while loop. At the moment it is displaying the name of the image so, for example, to display the thumbnail you would replace the `$image['iname'];` with `$image['ithumb'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM categories c, imagedb i
WHERE c.cid = i.icat
GROUP BY categories.cid
ORDER BY i.iid DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Php code must be something like

```
$conn = mysql_connect("host", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("db", $conn);

$query = mysql_query("[query above]");
$counter = 0;
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $results[$counter][] = $result;
    if (isset($results[$counter][4]))
    {
        $counter++;
        $results[$counter] = array();
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I get it to print out the results formatted like in the above question?